# Starting Android Camera with Intent crashes

Tags: java, android

i am new in the programming for Android. And I get a inexplicable Exception in my App and i hope you can help me. The app covers the following Use-Case:

1. The user press on the "take photo" Button
2. The Google Camera will be open
3. The Image will be save in the storage of the device
4. The Path, where the image stored will be listet in a listview
5. The user can click again on the button "take photo" (goto 2)

At firsttime the user can take photo succesful and the path will be show correctly in the app. But in case of clicking again the user can take a photo but the app crashes without a Exception when i want to save the image.

#### Scanning.java

```
package de.des;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import de.auftrag.R;

public class Scanning extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<String> pathlist;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scanning);

        final ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mimageView = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        pathlist = new ArrayList<>();

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.mylist, pathlist);

        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    private static final int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 1;
    public void takePhoto(View view) {

    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "fname_" +
            String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
    try {
        file.createNewFile();
        this.pathlist.add(file.getAbsolutePath());
        this.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("Scanning",e.getMessage());
    }

    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 3);

        }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    }

}
```

#### activity_scanning.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="de.des.Scanning">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnTakePhoto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str_take_foto"
        android:onClick="takePhoto"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSelectFile"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/str_read_file"
        android:onClick="selectFile"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnTakePhoto"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSelectFile"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="73dp" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

#### AndroidMainifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.auftrag">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity android:name="de.des.Scanning"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"/>
        <activity android:name="de.des.ObjektdatenMap" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Best wishes
Dominik

Comment: Hi. 

I see several issues here. Not sure if this is your complete code but you never call the takePhote (sic) method, your mimageView reference is not declared, and you never save your image. Could you clarify?

Comment: Since this is a runtime error I think you can leave the XMLs out of the question. They look fine to me

Comment: Hi, many thanks for your fast comment. For easy a fast and easy understanding of the problem i post only the important classes and xml files. I will call the takePhoto function with the onclick function of the button "btnTakePhoto" in the xml file. Please ignore the unused elements in the activity. I only want to open the camera dialog in android every time the user pressed a button.

Comment: Please specify the line where the exception is happening, its type, and the way you are setting paths up

Comment: The App is crashing after i pressed the agree arrow after taken a picture. But only at the second time of calling the intent. I dont get a Exception or log message. The Screen becomes black and i have to close the complete App.

Comment: I cannot help you this way. Best of luck

Comment: What does your file.createNewFile() do? You are already obtaning a file a couple of lines above. Secondly, don't call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() until inside onActivityResult() and you know for sure the photo was taken. FInally, are you sure you are getting the right code on startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 3) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
private static final int TAKE_PHOTO_CODE = 1;
public void takePhoto(View view) {
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "fname_" +
            String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    cameraIntent.putExtra("pic_path", file.getAbsolutePath());
    cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, TAKE_PHOTO_CODE);
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    switch (requestCode) {
        case TAKE_PHOTO_CODE:
            if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                String path = data.getExtras().getString("pic_path");
                pathlist.add(path);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad I could help you